# Être maqué(e) - how to use?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, argot

When someone is taken/in a relationship, on dit que cette personne est maquée.

Can anyone explain the usage of this expression more precisely? I know that the etymology comes from the world of prostitution, but I don’t understand how familar or vulgar it is to use “maqué” in a conversation.

Also, can a person say “je suis maqué(e)” or is it too pretentious? Is it better to say “j'ai quelqu'un”?

Comment: In Belgium, "je suis maqué" means "I'm completely astonished", "I've been left speechless". Nothing to do with the other usage (that I've learned from this question) since it's a loan from Walloon rather than a clipping of maquereau, but it's a potential source of confusion

Comment: @Eauquidort This definition of the Belgian ***maqué*** perfectly fits the French *esto**maqué*** although the similarity is clearly accidental.

Comment: @jlliagre Yeah that's where I assumed it was from as a kid. Looking into it, the Wal. verb it was borrowed from means to strike or to stun, and is onomatopoetic in origin.

Comment: [1883](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/164451).

Answer (score 2):

"Être maqué" is just an informal way (close to vulgar) to mean someone is in a relationship (often married, but not necessary). It's not used so often.

And yes, I can totally say "Je suis maqué" on a friends talk, but never on a professional context for example. I can totally say that a friend "est maqué", it's not insulting, just really informal.

Moreover, "Seul" means "Alone", so in your context, the contrary of "Maqué"

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it was not so common and slightly vulgar. I wrote "seul/e" by mistake, thanks for pointing that out. Besides the most common "je suis célibataire", what would you say are some other common ways of saying one is single?

Comment: [with a friend]

Comment: @alouette Je suis célibataie / Je ne suis pas en couple. But all these are contrary to Être maqué

Comment: I know, it was just a side question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Maqué" comes from the word "maquereau" which means "pimp". So, at first glance the expression “je suis maqué(e)” seems vulgar.

However, the [Larousse dictionnary](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_maquer/49302) says that "se maquer" means "to live in a household with someone" and is considered as "très familier" and not as "vulgaire".

So, two things to remember:

1. "Je suis maqué" means the contrary of  “je suis célibataire”.
2. "Se maquer" isn't a vulgar, be cautious though, since it should be used in informal contexts.

N.B. I can't help you further, since I am not French nor living in France.

Comment: "se maquer" could mean also "fréquenter", "s'accoquiner" in a more general sense. Ex : "moi je me maque pas avec les politiques".

Comment: I didn't know. It's interesting, since it is nearer to the original meaning of "maquer" or "maquereau".