# Quelle tournure ci-bas est la meilleure?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

1- Mon ami a contrarié mon plan de flirter avec un homme en lui disant que j’étais en couple.

2- Mon ami a fait obstacle à mon intention de séduire un homme en lui disant que mon coeur était pris ailleurs.

N’hésitez à me faire part d’autres tournures plus concises et plus fluides à l’oral. Sans nul doute existe-t-il d’autres manières plus spontanées de rendre corps à cette idée sans tomber dans la verbosité, c’est-à-dire l’outrance de termes superflus. Il faut croire que la spontanéité ne fait plus partie de moi depuis un certain temps, peut-être car je suis resté trop longtemps plongé dans des livres; à en croire Schopenhauer c’est bien ce qui arrive aux lecteurs avides, leur pensée se voit étouffée et ils peinent à enchaîner deux mots de suite… Merci d’avance.

Niveau de langue attendu: haut familier, standard.

Comment: Je connaissais *ici-bas*, *ci-dessous* ou *ci-après*, mais pas *ci-bas*.

Comment: @XouDo http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/BDL/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2422

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Mon pote a fait foirer mon plan drague en balançant que j'étais déjà maqué(e)...

---

Mise à jour :

Je viens de demander l'avis de mes « conseillers langue ado » et la seule correction indispensable concerne *plan drague* beaucoup trop *boomer* et qui ne se dit plus du tout, *plan cul* passe mais est peut-être trop direct. En revanche, *[maqué](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45186)* ne pose pas vraiment de problème mais peut être remplacé par *en couple* ou *qu'j'avais d'jà un mec/une meuf*.

Voici donc une version revue et corrigée :

> Mon pote a fait foirer mon *date* en balançant que j'étais déjà maqué(e)...

Comment: Ça sonne assez familier pour ne pas dire populaire! Il est vrai que je n’ai pas fait mention du niveau de langue attendu…Selon toute apparence, la tournure que tu m’offres me donne l’impression qu’elle est tout droit sortie de la bouche d’un paysan sans instruction.

Comment: Quand je m’exprime, je ne veux pas paraître d’un érudit emmerdeur au gros QI ni d’un colon sans éducation. Un juste équilibre entre les deux me rendrait satisfait!

Comment: Merci pour ta proposition.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Je ne crois pas qu'un paysan sans instruction s'exprimerait ainsi. Ce genre de phrase ne mène pas à l'Académie française, mais elle porte les signes d'une certaine instruction et dénote probablement un goût pour des œuvres telles [*Exercices de styles*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exercices_de_style) du très érudit Raymond Queneau.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Il n'y a rien de paysan là-dedans. C'est tout à fait plausible pour un ado d'une ville Française d'il y a quelques décennies, mais je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit tout à fait à jour : « maqué », les ados disent encore ça ?

Comment: @Pas un clue: merci pour l’information complémentaire! Je suis originaire de la province de Québec au Canada. Les termes qu’emploie jlliagre sont peu usités dans mon coin de pays sinon employés par la populace, c’est pourquoi je les ai apparentés à un registre de bas niveau.

Comment: @Jean-LouFrenette Nous sommes pays. C'est vrai que la phrase proposée n'a pas une saveur québécoise très prononcée, voire carrément pas la saveur érable pantoute, mais elle est délicieuse néanmoins, et d'une concision qui ne nuit ni à sa clarté ni à son élégance (selon une certaine conception de celle-ci du moins). En ce sens, elle dénote une certaine recherche.

Comment: @jlliagre: merci pour la version revue et corrigée!

Answer (score 3):

> Mon ami a contrarié mon plan de flirter avec un homme en lui disant que j’étais en couple.

Il y a un mélange de niveau de langue qui n'est pas du tout naturel. « Contrarié » est relevé et « ami » aussi dans ce contexte. « Flirter » est plutôt familier. « Plan » est un anglicisme, en français on dit « projet ». On peut parler de « plan drague » en langage familier, mais pas de « plan de … ».

> Mon ami a fait obstacle à mon intention de séduire un homme en lui disant que mon coeur était pris ailleurs.

À part la faute d'orthographe (« cœur » prend un o-e-dans-l'o), c'est du français soutenu.

En langage familier (peut-être plus style 2000 que 2020), je reprendrais volontiers la [proposition de jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/46690):

> Mon pote a fait foirer mon plan drague en balançant qu'j'étais déjà maqué(e)

En langage un peu moins familier je propose :

> J'ai flirté avec un homme, mais mon ami a cassé le coup en disant que j'étais déjà pris.

(Enfin, si on peut se retenir d'insulter l'ami au passage.) Question niveau de langue, « copain » serait plus adapté qu'« ami », mais « copain » est ambigu et dans ce contexte, on comprendrait que c'est la personne avec laquelle je suis déjà en couple, et pas un ami.

Comment: Je me demande dans quelle mesure le mélange des niveaux de langue manque de naturel. N'y a-t-il pas cette déclaration célèbre par exemple? «J’eusse été fâché que vous m’imputassiez cette connerie». Un article [ici](https://www.revuenouvelle.be/L-academicien-et-le-je-m-en-foutisme) étudie le mélange des styles et mentionne cet exemple et d'autres.

Answer (score 1):

Mon ami a fait échouer mon plan de séduire un gars en lui disant que j’étais déjà en couple